# How to scroll form in android app using appium

Tags: android, appium

I am testing android application

1. I am able to fill form up to certain fields which are visible on device
2. but now i want to scroll form and want to fill other fields and tap on submit button in last.

I am stuck here please help.

Comment: Please provide code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Put your code, please check how to ask on SO, rule: we don't code for you.

Answer (score 3):

My example is from python but it will work for Java as well just use java syntax to find element like

```
driver.find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("**/Put some text of scroll screen/**").instance(0))')
```

Or using java syntax

```
driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"**/Put some text of scroll screen/**\").instance(0))")
```

Comment: Using `UiScrollable` is a good idea, you can find more info on it on [official android developers site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html)

Comment: I am getting red error under UiScrollable, UiSelector() if i use above code

Comment: use these imports: import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;

Comment: from where i download these jars

Comment: your project must have appium  java Client Library jar https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aio.appium%20a%3Ajava-client

Comment: sorry for late reply as was out @PuneetKumar try this WebElement el = driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains('test').instance(0))");

Comment: Can you please share the imports you are using and extract line code from your ide

Comment: pls help i am stuck here, dont able to scroll in app

Comment: & also why u using double quotes its treating all code inside bracket as string

Comment: without seeing your code its difficult to help. Now i have done these implementations in my app testing for appium python

Answer (score 1):

// create a method name scrollTo or any name of your choice , with below mentioned code it will take parameter of text using which we want to scroll :

```
public void scrollTo(String text){                
      driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\").instance(0))");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap all that inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- Here you put the rest of your current view-->
</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView can contain just one item (only one layout as child)... so if you had something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- bla bla bla-->
</LinearLayout>
```

You must change it to:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <!-- bla bla bla-->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

For reference you can raed..

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

or Simple ScrollView example...

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-scrollview-example

Answer (score 0):

while testing your app using appium, use the below code to swipe vertically:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); 
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80); 
//Find endy point which is at top side of screen. 
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
//int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.10);
//Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width. 
int startx = size.width / 2; 

//Swipe from Bottom to Top. 
driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);
```

this will vertically swipe down your screen.

you can also try this line to scroll:

```
// Scroll till element which contains Tabs text.
driver.scrollTo("Tabs");
```

as you are facing with your android driver, declare it like below:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","fevicename");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
//add more according to your requirement
public AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Comment: its showing error //The method scrollTo(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver

Comment: so how you declare your appium driver? give the declaration here

Comment: public class GoldenGate {

 WebDriver driver;

Comment: now i am trying with AndroidDriver driver; lets see

Comment: now i am getting error The method scrollTo(String) is undefined for the type AndroidDriver

Comment: i updated the answer, first initialize and than use the method. Use the first one to swipe vertically instead of scrollTo()

Comment: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. for below codeDimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize(); 
  int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.80); 
  //Find endy point which is at top side of screen. 
  int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
  //int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.10);
  //Find horizontal point where you wants to swipe. It is in middle of screen width. 
  int startx = size.width / 2; 

  //Swipe from Bottom to Top. 
  driver.swipe(startx, starty, startx, endy, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.scrollTo("Tabs");
```

is no  more

In java client 4.0 version, scrollTo and scrollToExact are deprecated.
You have to use `driver.swipe()`

Comment: question asker does not need to drag and drop an element.... he needs to scroll his form. and also how you get the id !!!!!!!

Comment: Ok i apologize  i misunderstood it. You r right .. thanku. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code to swipe form with direction, it's working for me home this helps you.

The below is the code for swipe up and down

```
if (Direction.equalsIgnoreCase("Up")) {
            startX = size.width / 2;
            startY = ((int) (size.height * 0.80) - Offset);
            endX   = startX;
            endY   = (int) (size.height * 0.20);
        }
        //down
        else if(Direction.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {
            startX = size.width / 2;
            startY = ((int) (size.height * 0.20) + Offset);
            endX   = startX;
            endY   = (int) (size.height * 0.80);
        }

pointOption = new PointOption();

new TouchAction<>(getDriver()).press(pointOption.point(startX, startY)).waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
                .moveTo(pointOption.point(endX, endY)).release().perform();
```